# Mongo shell throws "ReferenceError db is not defined" even when I am connected and using that db?

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell, referenceerror

```sh
nicole@MacBook-Air client % mongosh
Current Mongosh Log ID: 6167b26073f2085eee4554b6
Connecting to:          mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?directConnection=true&serverSelectionTimeoutMS=2000
Using MongoDB:          5.0.3
Using Mongosh:          1.1.0

For mongosh info see: https://docs.mongodb.com/mongodb-shell/

------
   The server generated these startup warnings when booting:
   2021-10-13T15:36:00.307-07:00: Access control is not enabled for the database. Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted
------

test> show dbs
admin     41 kB
config   111 kB
local     41 kB
test    8.19 kB
test> use test
already on db test
test> show collections
users
test> test.users.find()
ReferenceError: test is not defined
test> users.find()
ReferenceError: users is not defined
test>
```

I'm new to mongo, and I just installed a local db on my Mac (Big Sur 11.4).

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/

```sh
brew tap mongodb/brew
brew install mongodb-community@5.0
brew services start mongodb-community@5.0
```

I just made a `users` collections via an express server using mongoose. I then opened up the database in my terminal to inspect the contents. However, I get a very strange error that tells me the database `test` is not defined, even though the shell tells me I'm using the `test` database. Is also says the collection `users` is not defined, but it is there??

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `db.users.find()`. For further reference see MongoDB Manual [mongosh Usage](https://docs.mongodb.com/mongodb-shell/run-commands/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your command is wrong. Use one of these:

```
use test
db.users.find()
db.getCollection("users").find()

db.getSiblingDB("test").users.find()
db.getSiblingDB("test").getCollection("users").find()
```

Comment: I thought db was a placeholder for the name of the db. Thanks, it works now.